# Investigate about wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I would like to know which wordpress theme is being used into the following website:

http://www.taxreclaimservice.co.uk/

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried asking them that question via mail or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I think its a custom made theme, because the current theme is not a child theme.